# how to write jQuery date time countdown function without use local machine time

Tags: jquery, date

**I want an jquery function which get any future date as input**
and do countdown using that date.

I found many function which uses local machine time i.e. `new Date()` function
but I don't want to use the local machine date time. When page load then I just want to display countdown from the future date.
I want countdown from server side date time.
so I want just

> a function which starts countdown from given date time without
>   comparing it with local machine time.

Comment: You need to get the current time from *somewhere* to compare it against the future date. Where are you planning on getting that?

Comment: thank you for your reply me. i means i don't want to compare with future date but want to start countdown from future date. i dont find such function which just do countdown of given date in jquery..

Comment: What are you counting down to? Say you start next year. So September 17th, 2014. Where you be when the countdown is done?